# audit usage history of site, pages and documents in SharePoint 2016 on-premise

Tags: audit-log-reports

Is there a way to get the number of visits of particular site, number of times document has been viewed stats can be found in SharePoint 2016 on-premise environment. Currently I am out of options and looking for any thing free tool or so to find out , also can powershell script be possible to find these details.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to use **[Audit log reports](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/view-audit-log-reports-b37c5869-1b47-4a82-a30d-ea20070fe527)**?

You should [configure](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/configure-audit-data-for-a-site-collection-a9920c97-38c0-44f2-8bcb-4cf1e2ae22d2) it first:

1. Activate "Reporting" site collection feature
2. Configure "Site collection audit settings" at *Site settings - Site Collection Administration*.
3. Generate report at *Site settings - Audit log reports* after data has been collected for several days.

P.S. IMHO, in SharePoint there is no unambiguous definition of what is considered a *site visit*.
For instance, if you want to just count every request of you site home page, you can even collect [IIS logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/provisioning-and-managing-iis/configure-logging-in-iis) from web server and parse it with [LogParser](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24659), counting rows where `cs-method` is GET and `cs-uri-stem` is your site relative path.
Example: `logparser -i:W3C "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\....\u_ex*.log WHERE cs-method = 'GET' AND cs-uri-stem = '/your-relative-site-url/'"`